# Laravel одна связанная запись

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

Есть две модели: Категория и посты. Мне нужно вывести все Категории и один пост (последний) каждой категории.

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post','category_id');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{   
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
//Получения данных
      $data = Category::with(['posts' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
          }])->get();
```

В данном случаи выводятся все категории и один только пост, а мне нужно из каждой категории вывести по посту.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function lastPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post','category_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
```